# Client Side Password Verification

Tags: library, javascript, php

Is there a JavaScript library that can verify a PHP `password_hash()`?

I am building an offline PWA and would like to download the password hash from my credentials database to my webpage where there would be a JavaScript based function to verify the password client side.